# What are the things a relative layout can do and linear layout can't

Tags: android, android-layout

we can nest relative layout into linear layout.
Can't we just use linear layout and its layout_width, gravity.. into relative layout and lot of other things that relative layout does. So why do we even use relative layout?

Comment: you are right you can create each layout with Linear Layout  or Relative layout but the difference is this : for example to create a page you need to add for 4 linear layouts , but it can be done with just 1 relative layout.

now in run time, there are 4 views that should be calculated and drawn , but for Relative layout there is just one view to be calculated and drawn
so performance is very better.

Comment: I don't see you face any problems in your question. StackOverflow is not for discussions or tutorial. Please specify your problem, or just check some tutorials about relative VS linear layout

Comment: `layout_alignTop` for example

Answer (score 0):

In the Relative layout, you can overlap more than 1 component. For example, if you want to show name on image, then you cannot do in a Linear layout, but in Relative layout, you can do it.